# Openstack Swift strange behaiour on copying back the Data Dirs

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

So, I am seeing some very strange behavior with Openstack Swift. If I start all the swift processes, and say do an operation (eg. upload a file), then if I kill all my Swift processes, copy all the data directories to some other temp location, delete the content of all the data directories, copy all the temp directories back to data dir and start my swift processes again, I am not able to perform a GET for the object. (I can access the container info but swift download fails).

I have spend hours debugging this very strange behavior. Anyone else has experienced this problem ?

Steps for reproducing the bug: (Assuming 4 Data Dirs say in /mnt/sdb1/ dir)

> => swift-init all start
>   => swift upload some_container some_file
>   => (Can be followed by any no of swift operations)
>   => swift-init all kill
>   => cp -R /mnt/sdb1/1 /mnt/sdb1/1_temp (copy from original to a temp dir)
>   => cp -R /mnt/sdb1/2 /mnt/sdb1/2_temp (copy from original to a temp dir)
>   => cp -R /mnt/sdb1/3 /mnt/sdb1/3_temp (copy from original to a temp dir)
>   => cp -R /mnt/sdb1/4 /mnt/sdb1/4_temp (copy from original to a temp dir)
>   => rm -rf /mnt/sdb1/1/*  (delete all the contents of original data dir)
>   => rm -rf /mnt/sdb1/2/*  (delete all the contents of original data dir)
>   => rm -rf /mnt/sdb1/3/*  (delete all the contents of original data dir)
>   => rm -rf /mnt/sdb1/4/*  (delete all the contents of original data dir)
>   => cp -R /mnt/sdb1/1_temp /mnt/sdb1/1 (copy to original from the temp dir)
>   => cp -R /mnt/sdb1/2_temp /mnt/sdb1/2 (copy to original from the temp dir)
>   => cp -R /mnt/sdb1/3_temp /mnt/sdb1/3 (copy to original from the temp dir)
>   => cp -R /mnt/sdb1/4_temp /mnt/sdb1/4 (copy to original from the temp dir)
>
> => swift-init all start (start swift again)
>   => swift list (this succeeds)
>   => swift list some_container (this succeeds)
>   => swift download some_container some_file (this fails)

This is very strange considering the fact that I just moved the content.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

Openstack Swift has some background process that check replication and consistency of its files. When you move the files by yourself, Swift will probably understand that as some kind of inconsistency depending on your cluster setup and will try to fix it. So, that is not supposed to work.

However, if you still wanting to discover what happens, I recommend you list your container content after the upload, move the files, and list you container content again. Wait a few minutes and list again. Move the files back and list again. That may help you to find out if the background process are doing something while you move the files.